# how to distinguish using past simple or present perfect?

Tags: tense

I wonder if there is any difference in meaning between these?

```
It’s years since I rode a bike. (it’s = it is)

It’s years since I’ve ridden a bike. (it’s = it is)
```

Thanks

In the following link, below the phrase *Since and tenses*, there is what I have already excerpted from:

[enter link description here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/since)

Comment: It would be great if you formatted the question and cited the source appropriately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I have already done what you asked me. I cannot get what you meant. Sorry.

Comment: Nima please take a look at how others edited your previous questions. To format examples, we use blockquotes, i.e. `> `. Also, you need to explain the link so we know what we're clicking at. "Source" is a bad link descriptor, but it's definitely better than "enter link description here". Thus, you don't see any reputable articles in the Net have link descriptors like that. Also, "thanks in advance" is a tagline, and taglines are discouraged in SE, just as much as politeness is encouraged. Please don't include them in your posts and please learn from editors.

Comment: What does this
" thanks in advance" is a tagline, and taglines are discouraged in SE, just as much as politeness is encouraged." mean?

Comment: @nima: The reasons for the general SE discouragement of fluff like "thanks in advance" can be found at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first example should be written as 
"It has been years since I rode a bike."(correct)
 
and the second example as 
"It has been years since I’ve ridden a bike."(not correct)

Perfect simple is used to describe actions happened within a span from a point in the past UP TO NOW on a timeline while Past Simple describes actions in a time dot on a timeline.

The first example is better because it tells people from the point in the past (that time I rode a bike) up to now, years have passed. In the second example, the point in the past is not structurally clear because "ride a bike" seems to be a longer time span.